# Настройка оверлея

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: Изображение]Помогите, пожалуйста, настроить оверлей.
Суть его в том, что при нажатии на Кнопку, появляется оверлей, чтобы его закрыть в появившейся форме достаточно нажать, Да или нет, и он пропадает.
Вопрос в другом, помогите сделать, чтобы можно было нажать по чёрному фону, и диалоговое окно и собственно сам оверлей пропадал, буду очень признательный.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test_Project
{
public partial class OverlayForm : Form
{
    public OverlayForm() : this(0.8)
    {
    }
    public OverlayForm(double opacity)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Opacity = opacity;
        bunifuElipse1.ElipseRadius = 5;
    }
    public void Show(Form owner)
    {
        Owner = owner;
        SetBounds();
        owner.SizeChanged += Owner_SizeChanged;
        owner.LocationChanged += Owner_LocationChanged;
        base.Show(owner);
    }

    void SetBounds()
    {
        if (Owner != null)
        {
            Location = Owner.PointToScreen(Owner.ClientRectangle.Location);
            Size = Owner.ClientRectangle.Size;
        }
    }
    private void Owner_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetBounds();
    }

    private void Owner_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetBounds();
    }
    public static DialogResult ShowDialogOnDarkBG(Form dialogForm, Form mainForm)
    {
        using (OverlayForm darkOverlay = new OverlayForm())
        {
            darkOverlay.Show(mainForm);
            return dialogForm.ShowDialog(darkOverlay);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Что-то я мало понял как нужно именно сделать, событие LostFocus, мне сделать в основной форме, где и вызывается Оверлей?

Comment: У меня имеется основная форма, это та форма, которая появляется при старте приложения.
Имеется 3 кнопки, нажав на одну из них, я вызываю новую форму, образно говоря, нажал на кнопку настроек, появляется новая форма настроек, и появляется оверлей(чёрный который). Идея такова, я хотел сделать, что если человек нажимает на чёрный фон он же оверлей, закрывается форма, и пропадает собственно сам оверлей.

Comment: Сделал, ничего не происходит, при нажатии на Оверлей, происходит только лишь сигнал от Windows.

Comment: Добавил на `OverlayForm` событие `Click` и в нём решил закрывать форму, и ничего не происходит.

Comment: Нечего показать, я неправильно всё сделал, и не понял о чём вы мне толдычили, теперь понятно что нужно сделать обработчик события click, и я так понял, в нём стоит отслеживать где именно человек нажал на кнопку?

Comment: Так я так и не пойму, что я щас сделать то должен?

Comment: Добавив её, ничего не изменилось. @aepot

Comment: Добавив в `public static DialogResult ShowDialogOnDarkBG(Form dialogForm, Form mainForm)
        {
            using (OverlayForm darkOverlay = new OverlayForm())
            {
                darkOverlay.Click += (s, e) => darkOverlay.Close();
                darkOverlay.Show(mainForm);
                return dialogForm.ShowDialog(darkOverlay);
            }
        }`
строчку `darkOverlay.Click += (s, e) => dialogForm.Close();` и ничего не происходит...

Comment: Моя цель как была, так она и осталась, ничего в принципе не изменилось.

Comment: @aepot Обновил, как код, так и сам вопрос.